# How to specify TrustRelationship of IAM role that will be used in many regions?

Tags: aws-cdk

I am creating one CDK stack that will create IAM roles. It will be deployed only once since roles are global. Second stack will use this role by finding it `Role.fromRoleArn(...)`. This role will be assumed by step functions. I have following CDK construcuct in roles stack:
`assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('states.amazonaws.com')`. When I look at generated role, I see following on Trust relationship tab: `The identity provider(s) states.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com`. There is addition of region where role stack is deployed (eu-north-1), although, I did not specify it. When I create role using IAM console there is no addition of region `The identity provider(s) states.amazonaws.com`.
My aim is to use single role regardles in which region second stack is deployed and States function in every region could assume that role.
Edited:
Same code adds trust relationships `lambda.amazonaws.com` and `apigateway.amazonaws.com`. For those relationships region is not added.
How to get rid of region from AWS Service when creating role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like not supported at the moment for sake of least privilege principle, see https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2999. You can try to open new feature request with your use case.

However, you still can use low level `Cfn` classes to achieve what you want - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.CfnRole.html#class-cfnrole-construct

Comment: If it is case of least privikeges, why region is not added to other two trust relationships which are specified (3 in total).  
Second: AWS Console does not add region when trust relationship is added.

Comment: AFAIK not all services have their region-specific representations, for those the service principal string is without region. The least privilege enforcement seems to be only on CDK construct, it is a "feature" of CDK, as specified in the Github link above.